# Fitrar campos de un webservice

Tags: java, http, webservice

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: necesito acceder a un servidor que me proporcione la temperatura de un lugar al indicarle cual es ese lugar, desde una aplicación java.
Por ahora eso lo consigo haciendo una petición http request el problema es que me dan demasiada información redundante y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de filtrar esos campos recibidos del servicio web para quedarme solo con los que me interesan que son las tempMax y temMin .
Les dejo acá mi código y la respuesta que recibo:

/// CODIGO JAVA

```
public class WeatherService extends HttpServlet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("\nOutput: \n" + callURL(
        // "https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/spain/madrid/madrid-766273"));

        System.out
                .println("\nOutput: \n"
                        + callURL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Madrid&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=f55938791241415bbd0917892e075f81"));


    }

    public static String callURL(String myURL) {
        System.out.println("Requeted URL:" + myURL);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myURL);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
            if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
                in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                        Charset.defaultCharset());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:" + myURL,
                    e);
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

/// RESPUESTA QUE RECIBO

Request URL:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Madrid&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=f55938791241415bbd0917892e075f81

Output:

```
<weatherdata><location><name>Madrid</name><type></type><country>ES</country><timezone></timezone><location altitude="0" latitude="40.4165" longitude="-3.70256" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="3117735"></location></location><credit></credit><meta><lastupdate></lastupdate><calctime>0.0094</calctime><nextupdate></nextupdate></meta><sun rise="2016-05-26T04:49:22" set="2016-05-26T19:35:01"></sun><forecast><time day="2016-05-26"><symbol number="804" name="overcast clouds" var="04d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="230" code="SW" name="Southwest"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="2.41" name="Light breeze"></windSpeed><temperature day="23.15" min="12.75" max="24.29" night="12.75" eve="23.4" morn="23.15"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="952.66"></pressure><humidity value="50" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="overcast clouds" all="88" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-05-27"><symbol number="800" name="clear sky" var="01d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="240" code="WSW" name="West-southwest"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="3.82" name="Gentle Breeze"></windSpeed><temperature day="24.11" min="11.12" max="25.63" night="12.01" eve="24.25" morn="11.12"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="955.35"></pressure><humidity value="49" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="clear sky" all="0" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-05-28"><symbol number="801" name="few clouds" var="02d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="251" code="WSW" name="West-southwest"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="6.61" name="Moderate breeze"></windSpeed><temperature day="20.66" min="10.44" max="20.66" night="11.98" eve="17.8" morn="10.44"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="955.48"></pressure><humidity value="52" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="few clouds" all="12" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-05-29"><symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"></symbol><precipitation value="0.61" type="rain"></precipitation><windDirection deg="259" code="W" name="West"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="4.16" name="Gentle Breeze"></windSpeed><temperature day="18.78" min="11.19" max="20.01" night="13.02" eve="18.24" morn="11.19"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="958.87"></pressure><humidity value="60" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="few clouds" all="20" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-05-30"><symbol number="800" name="clear sky" var="01d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="318" code="NW" name="Northwest"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="2.11" name="Light breeze"></windSpeed><temperature day="20.02" min="9.76" max="21.74" night="12.5" eve="21.12" morn="9.76"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="960.15"></pressure><humidity value="55" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="clear sky" all="0" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-05-31"><symbol number="500" name="light rain" var="10d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="75" code="ENE" name="East-northeast"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="1.55" name=""></windSpeed><temperature day="25.2" min="11.03" max="25.87" night="14.12" eve="25.87" morn="11.03"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="948.44"></pressure><humidity value="0" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="clear sky" all="6" unit="%"></clouds></time><time day="2016-06-01"><symbol number="800" name="clear sky" var="01d"></symbol><precipitation></precipitation><windDirection deg="63" code="ENE" name="East-northeast"></windDirection><windSpeed mps="1.46" name="Calm"></windSpeed><temperature day="26.77" min="11.33" max="27.27" night="14.92" eve="27.27" morn="11.33"></temperature><pressure unit="hPa" value="948.35"></pressure><humidity value="0" unit="%"></humidity><clouds value="scattered clouds" all="27" unit="%"></clouds></time></forecast></weatherdata>
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Porqué usas el modo `xml`? Te recomiendo usar el modo `json` cambia el mode por `mode=json`

Answer (score 1):

La URL contiene un información dentro de un XML, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Que te permitirán parsear el String recibido y hacer búsquedas por Tag, de esa manera solo obtendrás los datos que necesitas.
Y ya en el código:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename)); //filename sería tu String
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("time"); 
//tendrás que filtrar esta lista para que solo te entregue los datos del día deseado.
for (int i = 0; int < nList.getLength(); i++) {
Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
if (eElement.getAttribute("day")=="2016-05-27"){
     System.out.println("Máxima : " 
              + eElement.getElementsByTagName("temperature").item(0).getAttribute("max");
     System.out.println("Mínima : " 
              + eElement.getElementsByTagName("temperature").item(0).getAttribute("min");
     }
}
```

Más información: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, modificando la url del webservice `cnt=1` traerás sólo la información de hoy. (No deberías agregar tu API KEY, la cual debe ser privada, ahora cualquiera la podrá usar)

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Madrid&mode=xml&units=metric&cnt=1&appid=API_KEY
```

Ahora para obtener los valores de máxima y mínima debes parsear el xml. Puedes usar Java **XML DOM**.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File( file ));
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("temperature");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
         Node node = nList.item(temp);
         System.out.println("");    //Just a separator
         if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
         {
            //Print each employee's detail
            Element eElement = (Element) node;

            System.out.println("min:"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("min").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("min:"+eElement.getElementsByTagName("max").item(0).getTextContent());
         }
        }
```

Puede ser que debas hacer algún ajuste al código anterior ya que no tengo un IDE a mano para validar.

Un buen tutorial de XML DOM lo puedes encontrar acá: http://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xml-dom-parser-example-tutorial/